# Overload resolution failed vb.net

Tags: vb.net, overloading

I'm using Visual Basic 2010, and I keep on getting this error message (**Overload resolution failed because no accessible 'New' accepts this number of arguments.**) when I try to declare *myProducts*. I have no clue what I did wrong. Please help.

```
Dim Counter As Integer = 0

Private arrayProducts(9) As Products.Products.Products

Private Sub btnAdd_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnAdd.Click
    If Counter < 10 Then
        Dim myProduct As New Products.Products.Products(arrayProducts(Counter + 1),
                                                        CDec(txtItemNumber.Text), txtName.Text,
                                                        txtManufacturer.Text, CDbl(txtWholeSalePrice.Text), CInt(txtQuantity.Text))
        arrayProducts(Counter) = myProduct
        MessageBox.Show("Product is added to inventory.")
        Counter += 1
    Else
        MessageBox.Show("Sorry, inventory is full.")
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: No, I *definitely* see a New in your code.  I don't see the Products class, but am 100% sure that it doesn't have a `Sub New` that takes 6 arguments.  The compiler said so.

Comment: Please show you Products.Products.Products class. Please **don't** scale it further to become Products.Products.Products.Products etc.

Comment: I do have Sub New() in my Product class.

Comment: You need a sub New that takes the six arguments you are passing though...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this bit of code:

```
   Dim myProduct As New Products.Products.Products(arrayProducts(Counter + 1),
                                                    CDec(txtItemNumber.Text),
                                                     txtName.Text,
                                                    txtManufacturer.Text,
                                                    CDbl(txtWholeSalePrice.Text),
                                                    CInt(txtQuantity.Text))
```

Means that you must have a ctor (Sub New) which takes 6 args, probably something like this:

```
 Sub New(Index As Integer, ProdCode As String, ProdName As String,
         ManufacturerName As String, Price as Double, Quantity As Integer)
```

The error is saying it cannot find that constructor (ie that many arguments but the types would also have to be in that order `{Int32, String, String, String, Double, Integer}` ).  With that many args maybe you have one too many - or hard to imagine - one too few.  IntelliSence should have popped up the actual; arg list as you were typing.

You might find a `List` to be easier to work with than an old school array:

```
Friend ProdList As New List(Of Products.Products.Products)
....
Dim p As New Products.Products.Products(...<long arg list> )
ProdList.Add(p)
...
TextBox.Text = ProdList(DesiredProd).ProductName
```